# ASP MVC3 - set drop down list for multiple items

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, html.dropdownlistfor

On the edit page of my ASP MVC3 site, there is a portion of the code that deals with a dynamic number of agents attached to each model item. The code below is used to create the exact amount of table rows to display

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Fixed.Count; i++)
    {
        if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Fixed[i].AgentId))
        {
           <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Fixed[i].StateCode,
                 (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Fixed[i].AgentId)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fixed[i].AgentId)
            </td>
          </tr>                
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I am not sure how to display the property state code associated with each agent. Right now this code is the only area in the controller that deals with setting the drop down list values:

```
        SelectList tmpList = new SelectList(new[] { "AL", "AK", "AS", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "DC", "FM", "FL", "GA", "GU", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MH", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NA", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "MP", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PW", "PA", "PR", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "US", "VT", "VI", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY" });
        ViewBag.StateCodeList = tmpList;
```

Since there could be anywhere from 0 to 100 agents, the problem I am running into is displaying the proper state code associated with that particular agent in their respective drop down boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up finding the overload for this pretty quick:

```
                <td>
                  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Fixed[i].StateCode,
                      (SelectList)ViewBag.StateCodeList, Model.Fixed[i].StateCode)
                </td>
```

Comment: You should consider moving the `SelectList` to your view model (and use a view model if you're not). ViewBag should be avoided whenever possible.